# Reboot of Windows Machine Crashed my CentOS VM on VirtualBox

Tags: linux, crash, virtual-machine, virtualbox, centos6

After attempting to import data from one Oracle database to another on my D drive my computer started to hang and I had to manually reboot my machine. In doing so my virtualbox CentOS vm was hard rebooted as well. Now when I attempt to start my CentOS VM I get this error:

[image]

I went to this forum to see if they had a solution, but the solution for checking the 'Use host I/O cache' didn't work for me:

[virtualbox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=38523)

I also tried removing the vm instance and recreating a new instance with the same storage, but that didn't work either and I got the same error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Downvoters, the help center says I may ask questions that refer to:
a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers, and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. In other words, this question is on topic. Feel free to remove your downvote.

Comment: Is the storage for this CentOS VM also on the D drive you've been [having trouble with](http://superuser.com/questions/760799/my-d-drive-is-read-only)? If so, and that disk is still read-only, VirtualBox may not be able to write I/O cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that because the D: drive was dirty, I had to move over the CentOS virtual drive to the C: drive.